getting issue in ReactQuill with KAtex its giving output in Html but my expection it should be give string
import katex from "katex";
import "katex/dist/katex.min.css";
window.katex = katex;
const modules = {
  toolbar: [
    ["bold", "italic", "underline"], // toggled buttons
    // ["blockquote"],
    [{ list: "ordered" }, { list: "bullet" }],
    [{ script: "sub" }, { script: "super" }], // superscript/subscript
    [{ header: [1, 2, 3, false] }],
    ["image", { formula: { customClass: 'qlformula' } }],
    [{ color: [] }, { background: [] }], // dropdown with defaults from theme
    [{ align: [] }],
    ["clean"], // remove formatting button
  ],
  clipboard: {
    // toggle to add extra line breaks when pasting HTML:
    matchVisual: false,
  },
};
   <ReactQuill
     fullWidth
        name="mcqQuestion"
     // onChange={handleChange}
        onChange={(content, delta, source, editor) => {
        const isEmpty = !content.trim().replace(/<[^>]*>/g, '').length;
        setFieldValue('mcqQuestion', isEmpty ? '':content);
        }}
     value={values.mcqQuestion}
     error={Boolean(touched.mcqQuestion && errors.mcqQuestion)}
     helperText={touched.mcqQuestion && errors.mcqQuestion}
     modules={modules}
     formats={formats}
      bounds={".app"}
     style={toolbarStyles}
    />

i want it should return string value when we write mathematical expression, if write any string then its working, issue is happening with only formula
